# What values of x does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} (\frac{3}{(-1)^n+2})^n x^n$ converge for?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

In a past year paper there was a question asking to find the values of x in which  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} (\frac{3}{(-1)^n+2})^n x^n$ converges.

I tried using the root test, and so:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\frac{1}{n} (\frac{3}{(-1)^n+2}x^{n})^{1/n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^{1/n}} \frac{3}{-1+2^{1/n}} x$

And so we have a problem because $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 2^{1/n} = 1$ and we will get 0 in the denominator.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: $\sqrt[n]{x+y}\ne\sqrt[n]x+\sqrt[n]y$. Also note that root test computes $\limsup$ instead of $\lim$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that the coefficients of this power series is
$$a_n=\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{3}{(-1)^n+2}\right)^n=\begin{cases}\frac{3^n}{n},&n\text{ odd}\\
\frac{1}{n},&n\text{ even}\end{cases}.$$
Then for sufficiently large $n$
$$\frac{3}{n^\frac{1}{n}}\leq \sup_{N\geq n}|a_N|^{\frac{1}{N}}\leq 3.$$
Thus the radius of convergence is
$$R=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\frac{1}{3}.$$
Now we consider the case $|x|=\frac{1}{3}$. It's obvious that the series diverges when $x=\frac{1}{3}$. For $x=-\frac{1}{3}$, then the odd terms of the series are $-\frac{1}{n}$ and the even terms are $\frac{1}{n3^n}$, and the series also diverges in this case.

All in all, the series converges precisely when $|x|<\frac{1}{3}$.